# How do I use `whereFilter` in Firestore swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm a IOS development beginner.
I use firestore to make a IOS small app.
As I had need 'OR query', so make decision to use [whereFilter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#or_queries). [This](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Query#wherefilter_:) is API reference.

Xcode version 14.3.1

Tarket ios 16.2

```
let query = db.collection("cities").whereFilter(Filter.andFilter(\[
                 Filter.whereField("state", isEqualTo: "CA"),
                 Filter.orFilter(\[
                      Filter.whereField("capital", isEqualTo: true),
                      Filter.whereField("population", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: 1000000);
                 \])
\]))
```

But it don't work. and there is not in Xcode autocomplete.

I have imported Firebase, FirebaseCore, FirebaseFirestore, and FirebaseFirestoreSwift.

And I install and update all package dependencies related Firestore. And I have made index.

Comment: Make sure you're using at least version Firebase 10.7

Comment: @PaulBeusterien Thank you for your advice. Now Firebase package version is 9.6.0. I will try update Firebase package to at least version. and will try 'whereFilter' coding. Thank you.

Comment: @PaulBeusterien After updating to at least version, it work. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 2):

Use Firebase version 10.7.0 or higher.

`whereFilter` was introduced in 10.7.0. See the [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios) for details.